# Installing with brew, how do I securely override system vim?

Tags: macos, security, path, homebrew

I'm trying to upgrade to VIM 8 on OSX 10.12.6. I used homebrew to get it, but `which vim` still shows 7.4 as the current one.

This is in /usr/bin/vim, which is controlled by OSX, so I can't overwrite it without going to a lot of trouble (https://stackoverflow.com/q/32659348/5114). This is usually a sign that it's not the best way to do it. It could also cause system problems later, though I can't think of why something else in OSX would depend on vim.

I could re-arrange my path to add the homebrew paths before the system paths, but that has some security implications (an imposter of some binary in the non-system path would shadow the system binary of the same name if it got added somehow). It appears that some OSX systems have different default content in /etc/paths than mine (https://stackoverflow.com/a/34984922/5114).

I could use an alias in my .profile or .bashrc, but then if I'm in a shell or subshell where that isn't defined it will give me the wrong vim.

I want to ensure that I am not doing something unusual, insecure, or which risks system instability. What is the most correct and secure way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The *path* of least resistance is to change re-order your $PATH (pun intended) to have `/usr/local/...` folders come first.

But given your security concern, I would say the next best options are to either rename your homebrew version of vim (as in `vimm` or `Vim`) or always use an explicit path to your desired version of `vim`.